# How do I redirect the output of commands to file in silent mode in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

In GUI mode, commands like `CopyFiles` , `Delete` , etc. output their data to GUI (may be using `DetailPrint`) and their is a [function](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Dump_log_to_file) available on NSIS forums to copy that data (at the end of `section`) to a file.

Queries:

1. If the installer is being run in silent mode, how do I get the same data (which was being directed to GUI in non-silent mode) to the file?
2. In GUI mode, since I am directing custom logs through `DetailPrint` to the log file with the help of [function](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Dump_log_to_file) so that all the logs are received in order. Here the issue is that line breaks are removed from the custom logs. May be `DetailPrint` removes it. How shall I avoid this?

   Example:

   ```
   DetailPrint "This is a custom log1"
   DetailPrint "$\r$\nThis is a custom log2"
   /* 
     Dumped these logs using function mentioned above
     Output in logs(with no line breaks):
     This is a custom log1
     This is a custom log2

     Required output:
     This is a custom log1

     This is a custom log2
   */
   ```

Comment: Please put your relative code.. So we can suggest on it..

Comment: I have already mentioned the link of the function (to dump logs). If you are talking about second query then I have updated the post with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your Second query is Solved.

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
section
StrCpy $0 "$EXEDIR\install.log"
Push $0
    DetailPrint "This is a custom log1"
    DetailPrint "This is a custom log2"
    Call DumpLog
sectionend

;!define LVM_GETITEMCOUNT 0x1004
!define LVM_GETITEMTEXT 0x102D

Function DumpLog
  Exch $5
  Push $0
  Push $1
  Push $2
  Push $3
  Push $4
  Push $6

  FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
  GetDlgItem $0 $0 1016
  StrCmp $0 0 exit
  FileOpen $5 $5 "w"
  StrCmp $5 "" exit
    SendMessage $0 ${LVM_GETITEMCOUNT} 0 0 $6
    System::Alloc ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
    Pop $3
    StrCpy $2 0
    System::Call "*(i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i) i \
      (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, r3, ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}) .r1"
    loop: StrCmp $2 $6 done
      System::Call "User32::SendMessageA(i, i, i, i) i \
        ($0, ${LVM_GETITEMTEXT}, $2, r1)"
      System::Call "*$3(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN} .r4)"
      FileWrite $5 "$4$\r$\n"
      FileWrite $5  "$\r$\n"
      IntOp $2 $2 + 1
      Goto loop
    done:
      FileClose $5
      System::Free $1
      System::Free $3
  exit:
    Pop $6
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
    Exch $5
FunctionEnd
```

Your sample code is works for me. Its gives me output as your requirement.
Dont put  `"$\r$\n"` in Detailprint. Add `FileWrite $5  "$\r$\n"` in DumpLog function as i did. By this you will not have to put `$\r$\n` in each detail print.

Comment: Well, it seems that it is working directly. Let me check my code to see what is wrong with it.

Comment: As per your modified answer, line break will be added after each and every log. But that is not the requirement. Only few logs (not every log) will have line break. Here, the purpose is to group the logs of particular module together, add line break(s) and then add the logs of next module. It is required so that the logs do not seem to be messy.

Comment: May be if there is no direct solution, then workaround could be that we can add a tag for a line break in logs and then replace that with `$\r$\n` in function `DumpLog`. But this will not look good over the GUI, as that tag will appear on the interface.